# Check if date is greater than current date at 17:30

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have a date and a time parameters and I would like to check if that date/time is greater than the current date at 17:30.

I hope we could find a way using moment js. Is it possible?

I am trying this:

```
let d = moment(new Date()).set({hour:17,minute:30});
let t = moment(myDate).set({hour:paramHour,minute:paramMinute});

if ( t.isAfter(d) ) {
    console.log('true');
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So create a date at today and set the hour and minutes and compare it to the date you want to check. What did you try?

Comment: you don't need to involve 3rd party libraries. show you "date and time paramters" and some code you've tried. did you even bother to check mdn?

Comment: Yes, sometimes we are confused and less inspired, you know...and its when you ask for help. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need moment here. Something like this should work fine:

```
var now = new Date;
var cutoff = new Date;
cutoff.setHours(17, 0, 0, 0); /* Param Order: Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds */

if (now >= cutoff) {
    // Date is past 17:30
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, thats is it!

Comment: Sure thing. I also suggest checkout out the Date docs on MDN, they're pretty good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: You can set all the time values in one go: `cutoff.setHours(17,0,0,0)`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as comparing two typescript date objects:

```
(new Date(2016,11,21,2,53).getTime() > new Date(2016,11,21,5,30).getTime())
```

but of course, those Dates would not be defined like that - one would be passed in as a parameter and one would be created at runtime.

Comment: Yes, thats the thing, I need to define the date/today first and then separate hour from minute and create a new date to check.

Comment: see Yona's answer for getting today's date. new Date gets it automatically and then you can set the hours/minutes manually. then just compare with your parameter.